# R Shiny renderUI out gives numbers instead of actual label

Tags: r, shiny

I am building an app the should render a selectize drop down menu based on inputs from other select drop downs. The application should work this way:

Select-1 chosen -> Hive query run returning some data -> Part of that data is fed into renderUi selectizeInput as a vector -> Select-2 is populated with results from that query

All of it works but instead of displaying a label, it displays the row number. Example:

Should display:
[image: Select-1]

Actually Gives:

[image]

Those numbers are the order of the inputs in alphabetical order. I want the names not the number.

My code:

```
output$tag1 <- renderUI({
selectizeInput('tag1', 'Select input',data.frame(queryResult())[,1],options = list(maxItems = 2))        
})

uiOutput('tag1')
```

In the terminal the actual names of the drop down options are shown when chose but in the front end it shows the numbers. Hope someone can help solve the issue.

Comment: Looks like a factor/character problem, try `as.character(data.frame(queryResult())[,1])`? Can really help more without some data.